# Rails 4: Create record from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, models

I have 2 models, `User` and `Queue`.  And I want to be able to add the `@user.id` to the queue table from within the `users_controller`.

My models are:

```
class Queue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :queue
end
```

and my function in `users_controller` is:

```
def addToQueue
    queue_entry = Queue.new(user_id: @user.id) # where things go wrong
    if queue_entry.save
        redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "#{@user.name} has been successfully added to the queue."
    else
        redirect_to user_path(@user), :flash => {:error => "Error: #{@user.name} was NOT added to the queue."}
    end
end
```

I have a link for this function in the `show.html.erb` view for a `user` as: `<%= link_to 'Add to queue', addToQueue_path(@user) %>`

For some reason I keep getting: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` pointing to the line `queue_entry = Queue.new(user_id: @user.id)`

**How should I be doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set your relationship means that the users table has a foreign key `queue_id` and not the other way around.

Since an instance of a `User` `belongs_to` a `Queue` instance then `queue_id` has to be assigned as an attribute on the `User` instance.

Comment: hmmm that seems so counter intuitive because the queue will basically be queue to hold select users.  In other words I want my queue table to consist of select user IDs.  Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean

Comment: So yes once the user clicks on the link  "Add to queue" then you want that user to have a reference to the queue it belongs to thus the id of the queue needs to be present on the user instance and not the queue. Is that more clear ?

Comment: There should only be 1 queue.  And as I click "Add to queue", users should get added (to the same queue)..

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking this and should just have a field in the `User` model, for `in_queue`, and clicking this button changes it to `true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112440/discussion-between-cyzanfar-and-jeremy-thomas).